# Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I am trying to build an app, which has a feature of selecting several users. I have created a useState:

```
const [selectedStudents, setSelectedStudents] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

I have moved the setSeletedStudents function to other component using props and try to modify it like this:

```
   props.selectStudent((prev) => [
      ...prev, ...props.student.id,
    ]);
```

I have tried creating a function in original component an passing it to that component, also tried using the actual SelectedStudents instead of prev
The error I get:

```
Type 'number' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with restructuring the id property, which was unnecessary.

```
props.selectStudent((prev) => [
      ...prev, props.student.id,
    ]);
```